# jquery capturing data with .html() but its an iframe

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe, z-index, containers

I have jquery that gets data from another site:

**get.php**

```
<div>
displays a list of things
</div>
```

**home.php**

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"get.php",
    data:"fakedata=fakedata"
}).done(function(data){
    $(".container").html(data);
});
```

So it displays whatever is in get.php inside class container.

However, if I wanted to add something to get.php

```
<div>
<div style="position:absolute;top:0;left:-50;">
a box
</div>
displays a list of things
</div>
```

if I'm trying to show a box to the left of the container, then it will be cut off as if its an iframe. It doesn't work even if I add z-index to it.

Anyone know what I'm talking about?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"get.php",
    data:"fakedata=fakedata"
}).done(function(data){
    $(".container").html(data);
    $(".container").append("<div><div style='position:absolute;top:0;left:-50;'>a box</div>displays a list of things</div>");
});
```

this will append your divs to your container after the data

You can also make it ugly:

```
$(".container").html(data+"<div><div style='position:absolute;top:0;left:-50;'>a box</div>displays a list of things</div>");
```

hope it's want you looking for. check out jquery's html(), append() and text();

**notice the sigle quotes for the style inside the double quotes of the string. If you really need to use double quotes inside the string you'll need to escape them as in

```
var str= "<a onclick=\"alert('foo');\">click me</a>"`;
```

Comment: The reason I don't want to append just that is because these containers is within a while loop, so it has to have multiple containers

Answer (score 0):

I need to see the whole html, but this could help:

```
<div>
    <div style="margin-left:-50px;">
       a box
    </div>
    displays a list of things
</div>
```

Comment: That still gets hidden behind the .container